# Best way of porting code from the GPU to MPI-nodes

Tags: matrix, mpi, blas

I have a program, structured in two parts, $A$ and $B$. Both parts are capable of running as standalone units, and written in C++. $A$ is written for cluster systems, running entirely on CPU-nodes, connected via MPI (both on the same CPU for multiple cores and for different nodes), and $B$ is targeted to run on a single GPU. $A$ is doing FEM-calculations, while $B$ is only doing matrix-vector-multiplications, with a static dense matrix and varying vectors (matrix-size is typically 5kx5k-15kx15k complex double elements). The result of the matrix-vector-multiplication must be accessible from all threads in $A$.

In order to keep the memory load on the GPU as low as possible my strategy until now is to create the static matrix only in the first MPI thread in $A$, but the result matrix in all threads (giving me a large data chunk in GPU memory for the first thread, and small data chunks for all other threads) by creating as many instances of $B$ as there are threads in $A$, but only generating the matrix for one instance. After doing the multiplications in thread 0, the result is distributed using MPI to all the other threads. $A$ does calculations based on that result, and afterwards restarts $B$ with different parameters.

Now I have to port $B$ to the same nodes as $A$, without a GPU. I was looking at PBLAS-functions (PZGEMV) or the PLASMA-library, and at the Trilinos-library (which I already use in $A$, thus integration in $B$ should be easy), but there I am not sure if dense distributed matrix-vector multiplications are available. What would be the best strategy for porting, and to make the resulting program as efficient as possible?

Comment: How large is this static matrix? Could it make sense to have each process store a copy of the static matrix and perform the matvecs locally so you minimize communication costs? If the matvecs are time consuming enough, could you bundle a few cores into a single MPI process and use OpenMP or some library to do parallel matvecs within that bundled process and then send out the results to the other processes in your communicator?

Comment: As written in the question, the static matrix has a size between 25kk and 225kk elements (resulting in sizes between 400 Mbyte and 4 GByte, roughly). Thus, for the smaller matrix it is possible to share it, for the larger matrix I would like to avoid sharing it for each thread. Concerning bundling: I am not sure if I can bundle cores for OpenMP-procedures when each of them is running a MPI-thread

Comment: MPI+OpenMP is a common paradigm and storing one copy of the big matrix per node is desirable since communication costs are so much higher than computation. Try 1 MPI process per node with one OpenMP thread per core reach running a matvec. Alternatively, you could bundle your vectors into a smaller matrix and run a matmult for improved efficiency.